# Best approach to temporarily retain object using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Very short snippet:

```
#pragma mark - NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate

- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreServicesComing
{
    netService.delegate = self;
    [netService resolveWithTimeout:30];
}
```

In this example `- netServiceWillResolve:` is called in the same event loop. Then, `netService` is released (because of ARC) and rest have no chance to be called.

I don't like the solution with ivar. `NSNetService *` neither array. Is there better approach to "retain" `netService` until last delegate method is called?

Comment: Why don't you like the idea of a property? This is very common.

Comment: I like the idea of using `copy` to retain objects, but @ctrahey is right, using properties is the right thing to do here.

Comment: I see this property as redundant in my thinking of OOP. Also, I expect `netServiceBrowser` to get called multiple times and `netService`s callbacks can be called in another order so referring to one `NSNetService *` property can lead to bad state. This property could be array, but still I believe there is something better. But I will love explanation why is this property solution the best. But common do not have to mean best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000918-BCIGBIAA) explicitly says that the delegate is not retained and that is the normal pattern in Cocoa.  Also the documentation on [resolveWithTimeout:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000918-BCIIFEIH) says nothing about the NSNetService being retained until the delegate method has been called.  Under normal memory management rules (and I think this goes for ARC too) you can't make any assumptions about the lifetime of that object outside the scope of that method.

Or to put it another way, by not maintaining a strong reference to the object, you are saying "I'm not interested in this anymore, do away with it if you like".

Comment: Also, if you don't keep a reference to the `NSNetService`, you won't be able to unset yourself as the delegate. Given that you know nothing about the lifetime of the service (some other object may keep another reference to it), this could very well crash your app with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when the service tries to send you a delegate message. That's why you should `-setDelegate:nil` in your class' `-dealloc` implementation for all objects you've set yourself up as a delegate. Of course, the only way you can do this is by keeping a reference to those objects.